# How can I use Chinese Fonts in DomPdf

Tags: php, dompdf

Currently I am using domPdf with my core php code and trying to generate a PDF file with Chinese Characters. But unfortunately the Chinese Characters will automatically turned into "????" or in sometimes in square boxes.

Can someone suggest me how can I achieve this task. Thanks!!

Comment: Did you read the readme on github ??
https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf#about-fonts--character-encoding

Comment: If you are still looking for solution, mPDF also can generate Chinese word using specific Font family. More information: https://mpdf.github.io/fonts-languages/cjk-languages.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for feedbacks.!! I have found a solution from github.com/dompdf/dompdf#about-fonts--character-encoding – Allen Chak